# How are widgets such as Intercom.io and Olark using the parent domains cookie?

Tags: javascript, json, iframe, cookies, intercom

I've built a widget that I enclosed inside an iFrame, but I'm having difficulty sending the cookies created on the parent domain to the iframe domain for use. The parent and iframe domains are different, so cross-domain rules apply.

Is there a standard way of creating widgets that lets the parent and iframe to communicate with each other? Possibly using Ajax with JSON or JSONP?

EDIT: I can't even get the iframe to print the cookie inside the iframe unless they're both from the same origin.